# Advanced Custom Fields プラグインで位置ルール、カテゴリを削除時の挙動を変えたい

Tags: wordpress

WordPressでACF(Advanced Custom Fields)プラグインを利用しています。

位置ルールを、
【投稿タクソノミー】【等しい】【カテゴリA】
と設定していたのですが、その後カテゴリに変更があり
「カテゴリA」を削除した際に、位置ルールが
【投稿タクソノミー】【等しい】【未分類】
に書き換わっていました。

カテゴリを削除した際に、位置ルールに削除したカテゴリが含まれる場合は
ルール自体が自動的に削除されるようにしたいのですが、
どのように実現できますでしょうか？

ご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

正攻法ではありませんが、カテゴリー削除時に`delete_term_taxonomy`のフックを利用してACFの設定データの中から削除対象のカテゴリーのスラッグを探し、ヒットしたらACFの設定値を上書きで出来ると思います。

ACFの設定は`wp_posts`に投稿として保存され、ルールは`post_content`内に保存されます。
これを`wp_update_post()`で上書きすればACFの管理画面で更新を押さない限りルールは消えます。

Comment: ご教示いただき、ありがとうございます。やってみます！